# covariantly constant one form

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-forms

Let $v$ be a vector field. We say that $v$ is covariantly constant iff

\begin{equation}
\nabla v=0,
\end{equation}
where $\nabla v= (\partial_j v^i+\Gamma^i_{jk} v^k) \ \partial_i \otimes dx^j$, 
i.e. the total covariant derivative of $v$ is zero.
Now let $v=\omega^{\sharp}$ be a rised one-form. Therefore
\begin{equation}
\nabla v=\nabla(\omega^{\sharp})=\ldots
\end{equation}
is there a way to simplify this expression? 
I would like that expresion to be in terms of $\omega$. I've tried simply $\nabla \omega = 0$, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "it doesn't work".  It works, since you have the metric (hence musical isomorphism) is parallel.

Start with the Leibniz rule:
$$
\begin{align*}
X(\omega(Y))&=(\nabla_X\omega)(Y)+\omega(\nabla_XY)\\
X\langle v,Y\rangle&=\langle\nabla_Xv,Y\rangle+\langle v,\nabla_XY\rangle
\end{align*}
$$
Equating them gives
$$
(\nabla_X\omega)(Y)=\langle\nabla_Xv,Y\rangle
$$
so $\nabla_Xv=(\nabla_X\omega)^\sharp$, i.e., $\nabla(\omega^\sharp)=(\nabla\omega)^\sharp$.